# How to read remote video on Amazon S3 using ffmpeg

Tags: amazon-s3, ffmpeg

I need to create poster frames from videos hosted on Amazon S3 via ffmpeg.

So is there a way to use the remote video file directly in ffmpeg command line like this:
`ffmpeg -i "http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/video.mp4" -ss 00:00:10 -vframes 1 -f image2 "image%03d.jpg"`

ffmpeg just returns:
`http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/video.mp4: I/O error occurred

Usually that means that input file is truncated and/or corrupted.`

I also tried forcing ffmpeg to use the videos mp4 container for reading:
`ffmpeg -f mp4 -i "http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/video.mp4" ...`
But no luck.

Wget this video from S3 and processing it locally works fine of course,
as well as reading the file remotely from other 'standard' http servers.
So I know that ffmpeg supports remote file reading, but why not on S3?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Nevermind, I found an easy way to solve my problem.

I set up an amazon cloudfront download distribution pointing to my S3 bucket.
Via cloudfront the files are accessible with ffmpeg over http:

```
ffmpeg -i "http://subdomain.cloudfront.net/video.mp4" -ss 00:00:10 -vframes 1 -f image2 "image%03d.jpg"
```

And the data transfer is even cheaper!
But still wondering why this won't work with S3 directly...

Comment: I had the same issue, pulling from the bucket directly doesn't work.   It also didn't work pulling the video through Limelight's CDN.   Only worked via cloudfront.    Very strange..

Comment: Works for me when I add bucket policy

Comment: I think it may help to specify the `-ss` value first, re: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534835/fastest-way-to-extract-a-specific-frame-from-a-video-php-ffmpeg-anything

Comment: @LukaszMadon what bucket policy did you add?

Comment: how do we  access the ffmpeg on aws lambda?

Answer (score 28):

For everyone who came here looking how to do this with S3 only, The AWS SDK can now generate presigned urls.

```
ffprobe -i "$(aws s3 presign s3://MY_BUCKET/MY_FILE --expires 5)"
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful!  The current link to the .Net SDK page presign is https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLDotNetSDK.html

Answer (score 11):

In my case, reading directly form S3 bucket work like a charm.
To be more specific, my S3 object has private permission so I'm passing a Signed-URL to ffmpeg.

I use ruby and AWSRubySDK to generate a Signed-URL.
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#url_for-instance_method

Check your S3 object's permission.

Comment: What specific command did u use with ffmpeg for signed urls ? I'm getting bad request error. Also it works perfectly fine for normal urls.