# how to get an image from the url video (stored on s3 bucket)

Tags: python, image, url, video, amazon-s3

I want to get an image from url video stored on s3 bucket.
I tried to do it with cv2.VideoCapture but it only works with static file.
If someone can help me

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show us what you have tried, before we can help you out here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read remote video on Amazon S3 using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677317/how-to-read-remote-video-on-amazon-s3-using-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its too late but I'm writing this for other facing same problem, since I was trying but couldn't found any solution.

So you have to set up amazon cloudfront download distribution pointing to your S3 bucket (if don't know how to setup please see [here](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/create-a-cloudfront-distribution.html)) and then simply access using http (not https, don't know why it not working with https or directly via s3 url).
Just put cloudfront url as:

```
cv2.VideoCapture('http://xyz.cloudfront.net/myvideo.mp4')
```

Now it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

A [presigned url](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_url) for S3 object can be used.

`url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url( ClientMethod='get_object', Params={ 'Bucket': bucket, 'Key': key } )`

`vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)`